# How to determine appropriate dimensions for ExpandableListView groupIndicator icons?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm working on an app that involves and ExpandableListView.  We should like to replace the groupIndicator with one of our own choosing.

I created a spec for the indicator that would show a different png depending on the state of the selector (expanded or not expanded)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"/>    
</selector>
```

I then set up my layout xml to use:

(Note that childDivider is a one pixel tall png rather than a color because setting that to a color seems to be bugged)

This works, except that our icon is stretched out vertically.  That makes sense, because we just created a 25x25 icon and hoped for the best.  I'm trying to figure out the dimensions of the native icon so that I can match it, but that's where I run into trouble.

Digging through the source code (ExpandableListView.java) I found that, by default, the class will use com.android.internal.R.styleable.ExpandableListView_groupIndicator.  So I have an id, but no icon yet.

I'd love to be able to do:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), com.android.internal.R.styleable.ExpandableListView_groupIndicator);
        imWidth = image.getWidth();
        imHeight = image.getHeight();
```

But as the "internal" suggests, it's not visible to me in user space.

I also found getIndicate() in ExpandableListView.java, but it is private, so I can't get to that either.

I'm quite new to diving into the platform source code, and I don't know how else to track down that image.  Can anyone help me out?

Edit: Thanks CommonsWare.  To spell out the rest for anyone else looking:

android:drawable/expander_group is defined in /frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/expander_group.xml.
expander_group.xml mentions that it uses @drawable/expander_ic_maximized and @drawable/expander_ic_minimized.
Those drawables can be found in /frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/expander_ic_maximized.9.png and /frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/expander_ic_minimized.9.png, among other places for specific densities and such.  The "9" explains why the default icons don't have distortion problems - they're patch-9 graphics.  The density-agnostic versions of the icons are 34px by 38px.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`base.git`'s `core/res/res/values/styles.xml` defines `com.android.internal.R.styleable.ExpandableListView_groupIndicator` as `android:drawable/expander_group`. That is a `StateListDrawable` in your SDK's copy of the resources. The underlying PNGs are of varying sizes based upon density.

Comment: Hi Mark.  Loved your Advanced Android book, thanks for writing it.  Thanks also for this answer, I was able to find the resource folders and the right files with your help.

Comment: @MaximumGoat: Glad the answer and book are useful!